# How do I append a div or run a call back function after jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a span after a dynamically loaded file but I can't get it to work. The below function runs fine but I just can't run a call back function or append the span.

```
//The jquery click event is here
jQuery(this).parents('.buttons')
.next('.response')
.load('example.php', {
                postid: id,
                Count: ResponseCount
                //I'm trying to run a call back function here but 
                //it's not working.
            });
```

Comment: you need to have your callback outside your data, so after the last `}`

Comment: What I am seeing is an object not a callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.load()` method allows for a thrid parameter which is the "on complete" callback. You could use it as follows, to achieve the desired functionality:

```
//The jquery click event is here
jQuery(this)
.parents('.buttons')
.next('.response')
.load('example.php', {
                postid: id,
                Count: ResponseCount
            }, function() {

   // This div will be appended when load() completes successfully
   $(this).append($('<div>My appended div</div>'))

});
```

For more information on `load()` [see the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/)